# expectation of squared summation

Tags: probability-distributions

How does the expectation of this:

$$E\Bigg[ \bigg(\sum_{n=1}^{N}  x_n \bigg)^2\Bigg]$$

Equal this:

$$E\Bigg[ \bigg(\sum_{n=1}^{N}  x_n \bigg)^2\Bigg]=N(N\mu^2+\sigma^2)$$

I'm also told that  x is Gaussian and i.i.d:

$$E[x] = \mu$$
$$E[x_n^2] = \mu^2 + \sigma^2I_{ij}$$

$$I_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 & i=j\\
0 & i\ne j \\
\end{cases}$$

$$\mu_{ML} = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{n=1}^{M}x_n$$

$$\sigma^2_{ML}=\frac{1}{M}\sum_{n=1}^{M}(x_n-\mu)^2$$

Answer (score 4):

You can write the square of the sum as a double sum.
$$E (\sum_{n=1}^N x_n)^2 = E(\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N x_i x_j)
= \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N E[x_i x_j]$$

Then note that
$$E[x_i x_j] = \begin{cases} \mu^2 & i \ne j \\ \mu^2 + \sigma^2 & i = j \end{cases}$$

Comment: Cool!  Then there would be $N^2$ of $\mu^2$, and $N$ of $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Two formulas about i.i.d. sums of variables (Gaussian or not):
$$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}
\E\,\!\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)=n\E(X)\tag1
$$
$$
\Var\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)=n\Var(X)\tag2
$$
The variance is the expectation of the squares minus the square of the expectation:
$$
\Var\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)=\E\,\!\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^2\right]-\E\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^2\tag3
$$
Putting these together:
$$
\E\,\!\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^2\right]=n\Var(X)+n^2\E(X)^2\tag4
$$